# Disable dynamically created multiselect (using a plugin) dropdown in angular

Tags: angular

I have added a multiselect dropdown to each row of a table data, using which user can change the selection and save it.

The settings of the multi select dropdown in ts(typescript) file.

Now I want to disable dropdown in some rows based on some user conditions. But changing the settings (disable property to true) is disabling all the dropdowns in the table.

I am using and following the following git example.
https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/disablemode

Sample html code I have used

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items;>
    <td> {{item.name}} </td>
    <td>
        <angular2-multiselect [data]="dataArray" [settings]="dropdownSettings"></angular2-multiselect>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Sample settings (in typescriptfile)

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
        singleSelection: true,
        primaryKey: 'dataId',
        labelKey: 'dataName',
        text: "Select a value",
        enableSearchFilter: true,
        lazyLoading: true,
        showCheckbox: true,
        clearAll: false,
        disabled:false
    };
```

[image: Dropdown in each row]

Comment: your settings object needs to be per dropdown for this to work, and then you can change the disabled property according to any condition you want. You will have to provide more code for a more specific answer

Comment: the dropdown is dynamic, as I don't know how many controls are going to be there.

Comment: how do you decide if each item is disabled or not?

Comment: There will a check box above the table to disable the dropdown with value Afternoon (it's id/key value is 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is create a unique settings object for each item, in your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items;>
    <td> {{item.name}} </td>
    <td>
        <angular2-multiselect [data]="dataArray" [settings]="getDropdownSettings(item)"></angular2-multiselect>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and then in your component:

```
getDropdownSettings(item) {
    const isDisabled = true; // change to the logic you want here, like item.id === 1;
    return {
      ...this.dropdownSettings,
      disabled: isDisabled,
    };
  }
```

this code creates a new (unique) settings object for each item in your ngFor